# Send files to folders using bash script

Tags: bash, file, directory

I want to copy the functionality of a windows program called files2folder, which basically lets you right-click a bunch of files and send them to their own individual folders.

So

> 1.mkv 2.png 3.doc

gets put into directories called

> 1 2 3

I have got it to work using this script but it throws out errors sometimes while still accomplishing what I want

```
#!/bin/bash

ls > list.txt
sed -i '/list.txt/d' ./list.txt
sed 's/.$//;s/.$//;s/.$//;s/.$//' ./list.txt > list2.txt
for i in $(cat list2.txt); do
mkdir $i 
mv $i.* ./$i
done

rm *.txt
```

is there a better way of doing this? Thanks

EDIT: My script failed with real world filenames as they contained more than one . so I had to use a different sed command which makes it work. this is an example filename I'm working with

> Captain.America.The.First.Avenger.2011.INTERNAL.2160p.UHD.BluRay.X265-IAMABLE

Comment: What errors do you get "sometimes"? Oh I guess it is the `.` and `..` directories.

Comment: mv: cannot stat 'foo.*': No such file or directory but checking the contents of the directory shows everything is ok

Comment: It's not very clear what you want. Where does a file called `simon` go? What about one called `abc-7.txt` ? What about `345-678.doc` ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are getting errors on `.` and `..` so change your call to `ls` to:

```
ls -A > list.txt
```

> -A      List all entries except for . and ... Always set for the super-user.

You don't have to create a file to achieve the same result, just assign the output of your `ls` command to a variable. Doing something like this:

```
files=`ls -A`
for file in $files; do
  echo $file
done
```

You can also check if the resource is a file or directory like this:

```
files=`ls -A`
for res in $files; do
  if [[ -d $res ]];
  then
    echo "$res is a folder"
  fi
done
```

Comment: Oh I did not see that you actually removed these entries =) Anyways use -A flag and you don't need to filter anything.

Comment: Also there is no need to actually create a file for this, pipe the output of `ls` to a variable instead.

Comment: can u give me an example of how I would do that?

Comment: Done. The above will still not solve the errors you sometime gets, but I think it is more appropriate since you don't have to filter and create any temporary file =)

Comment: Oh, sorry didn't test the above =) Now it should work.

Comment: hey so i can add comments to explain what everything is doing in my script, i think u misunderstood whats happening and why, the only other method i found online of achieving the objective was using arrays which i don't know how to use, Ill edit the question and add comments.

Comment: Huh doesn't the above work for you? I made changes =)

Answer (score 0):

This script will do what you ask for:

`files2folder`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

for file; do
  dir="${file%.*}"
  { ! [ -f "$file" ] || [ "$file" = "$dir" ]; } && continue
  echo mkdir -p -- "$dir"
  echo mv -n -- "$file" "$dir/"
done
```

Example directory/files structure:

```sh
ls -1 dir/*.jar
dir/paper-279.jar
dir/paper.jar
```

Running the script above:

```sh
chmod +x ./files2folder
./files2folder dir/*.jar
```

Output:

```sh
mkdir -p -- dir/paper-279
mv -n -- dir/paper-279.jar dir/paper-279/
mkdir -p -- dir/paper
mv -n -- dir/paper.jar dir/paper/
```

To make it actually create the directories and move the files, remove all `echo`

Comment: hey thanks for the comment i had to edit my script because it failed with files with more than one . in the name I'm working with media files, tested on simple directories but it failed on more complex names have edited the original script with new sed command, your script doesn't seem to do anything with bigger file names.

Comment: @HaniUmer I have difficulties understanding your comment. does't seem to do anything with bigger file names what does it mean?

Comment: @HaniUmer modified script to only remove the rightmost dot extension and tested it working properly with a `Captain.America.The.First.Avenger.2011.INTERNAL.2160p.UHD.BluRay.X265-IAMABLE.divx` filename